# Django app is blocked when calling linux ping

Tags: python, django, ping

I need to verify whether a host is available, so I use os.system("ping -c 1 %s" % host) to check it. if the host is available, the code works well, but when the host is unavailable, the call will not returned forever.
Here is my code in view.py:

```
def go(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    host = request.GET.get('host')
    if not verify_host(host):
        return HttpResponse("Host not available!")

def verify_host(host):
    cmd = "ping -c 1 -W 5 %s" % host
    if os.system(cmd):
        return False
    return True
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cmd = "ping -c 1 %s -W 2" % host
```

-W is for timeout.

It is not a python issue. The command blocks

EDIT: 
It works fine.
try this
Code:

```
import os
host="10.13.1.23"
def verify_host(host):
    cmd = "ping -c 1 -W 5 %s" % host
    if os.system(cmd):
        return False
    return True

print verify_host(host)
```

Output:

```
$python file.py
PING 10.13.1.23 (10.13.1.23) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.13.1.23 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

False
```

Comment: I also tried this command, but it still blocked. It seems the ping parameter is not passed somehow.